# We need to ensure that, for dotnet, Java, Salesforce, only BE Or ME trainers are allowed validation rule for it. e

Tags: validation

```
AND(
    ISPICKVAL(course_c, 'dotnet'), 
    NOT(ISPICKVAL(education -_c, 'BE'))
)
```

or

```
AND(
    ISPICKVAL(course_c, 'Salesforce '), 
    NOT(ISPICKVAL(education_c, 'ME'))
)
```

Comment: Hi @mounica, and Welcome to the Salesforce Stackexchange platform! Please review "How do I ask a good question?" here: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

I find it much easier to think of validation rules as *in*validation rules. You're not telling it what data is valid, you're telling it what data is invalid (if the validation rule formula evaluates to `true`, the DML operation fails).

The first step is to write it out in plain language. In your case, that'd be something like:
*If the course is Dot net or Java or Salesforce, and the education is not ME and not BE, then complain*

That'll usually give you the structure you can use in the validation rule, and for simple ones like this the translation is almost word for word (aside from using prefix notation like `+ 1 2` instead of infix  like `1 + 2`)

```
AND(
    OR(
        /* 3 separate calls to ISPICKVAL() to check the course */
        /* This part is an exercise left to the reader */
    ),
    NOT(ISPICKVAL(Education__c, 'ME')),
    NOT(ISPICKVAL(Education__c, 'BE'))
)
```